# Is there a website or tool for parsing, breaking down, and explaining x86 bytecode

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly, machine-code

When you type a shell command in https://explainshell.com/ , you get an explanation of each part of the command and what the command does.

Is there a place where I could type in a bunch of x86 bytecode, and have it paresed byte by byte (and perhaps bit by bit for certain bytes) and explained similarly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disassemblers will decode whole instructions back into asm.  Some will group the bytes into prefixes, opcode, and later stuff**.  e.g. a 4-byte immediate or displacement in an addressing mode might be grouped without spaces, but separated from the opcode by a space.

Agner Fog's objconv disassembler does that.  https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv

e.g. on a random `.o` file I had lying around from a recent SO question about x87 flags.  Note that it's a `.o` so the addresses are based at `0` in each section.

More importantly, not how `fld dword [value1]`'s machine code is show as `D9` (the opcode), `05` (the ModRM byte that encodes the addressing mode and in this case signals that there's a 4-byte displacement), and the `00000000` with a (d) note showing the 4-byte `disp32`.

```
;; Produced with
;; objconv -fnasm  fcomtest.o  /dev/stdout

global _start

SECTION .text   align=1 execute                         ; section number 1, code

_start: ; Function begin
        fld     dword [value1]                          ; 0000 _ D9. 05, 00000000(d)
        fcom    dword [value2]                          ; 0006 _ D8. 15, 00000004(d)
        fwait                                           ; 000C _ 9B
        fnstsw  ax                                      ; 000D _ DF. E0
        pushfd                                          ; 000F _ 9C
        sahf                                            ; 0010 _ 9E
        pushfd                                          ; 0011 _ 9C
        ja      greater                                 ; 0012 _ 77, 0E
        jc      lessthan                                ; 0014 _ 72, 18
        mov     eax, 1                                  ; 0016 _ B8, 00000001
        mov     ebx, 0                                  ; 001B _ BB, 00000000
        int     -128                                    ; 0020 _ CD, 80
greater:mov     eax, 1                                  ; 0022 _ B8, 00000001
        mov     ebx, 2                                  ; 0027 _ BB, 00000002
        int     -128                                    ; 002C _ CD, 80
lessthan:
        mov     eax, 1                                  ; 002E _ B8, 00000001
        mov     ebx, 1                                  ; 0033 _ BB, 00000001
; Note: Function does not end with ret or jmp
        int     -128                                    ; 0038 _ CD, 80
; _start End of function


SECTION .data   align=1 noexecute                       ; section number 2, data

value1:                                                 ; dword
        dd 412EC49CH                                    ; 0000 _ 10.923 

value2: dd 4091B3D0H                                    ; 0004 _ 4.5531998
```

There's probably a way to run `objconv` on a chunk of raw bytes, not in a `.o`, or if not you could put it in one.

---

**The overall structure of x86 machine code is fairly fixed:**

```
[prefixes ...]  opcode [modrm [sib] [disp0/8/32]] [imm8/16/32]
```

Some opcodes have no modrm (e.g. `mov reg, imm32`), many have no immediate (e.g. `add r32, r/m32`), some have both (e.g. `add r/m32, imm8`), some have neither (e.g. `lodsb`, or `cdq`).

see http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html for an opcode map.  And of course Intel's manuals (which are indexed by mnemonic, not opcode), e.g. HTML extract https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/

IDK if anyone's built an online tool like you're picturing, or other disassemblers that do what objconv does.